# How to fetch a specific attribute and put it in a collection in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I would like to fetch a specific attribute and put it in a collection. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
   foo: "lorem ipsum",
   bars: [{
       a: "a",
       b: {c: "d", e: "f"}
   }, {
       a: "u",
       b: {w: "x", y: "x"}
   }]
}
```

I understand how to fetch only `bars` (and not `foo bars`) and get it returned somewhere by using [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse), but I would like to fetch `bars`, identify a certain object using attribute `a` and then put `b` inside of a collection.

My idea is to do something like

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: "someUrl",

    parse: function(data) {
         data.bars.each(function(bar) {
             if (bar.a == i) {
                 return bar.b;
             }
         }
    }
};

var myCollection = new MyCollection();
myCollection.fetch({
     success: function() {
          console.log("Proper collection of the correct 'b'!");
     }
});
```

I am having trouble knowing where and how to pass the `i` for the `if(bar.a == i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you pass to `fetch` are forwarded to `Collection.parse` and that means you can write something like this:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: "someUrl",

    parse: function(data, opts) {
        console.log(opts);

        // I took the liberty of replacing your filter
        var matches = _.where(data.bars, {a: opts.i});
        return _.map(matches, "b");
    }
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();

// pass your filter as an option when you fetch you collection
myCollection.fetch({
    i: "u", 
    success: function() {
        console.log("Proper collection of the correct 'b'!");
    }
}).then(function() {
    console.log(myCollection.toJSON());        
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/v57rpgu9/

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply.

I have adapted your solution to my problem, and right before the parse function returns, I do console.log(_.map(matches, "b") and it displays the EXACT list of objects I would like to collect. However, it doesn't reach the success part. It gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined  backbone-min.js:1. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Maybe an access to a `a` attribute in `MyModel.parse`. Try to remove `model: MyModel,` in your collection definition like I did in my demo and see what happens

Comment: Thank you again. Removing `MyModel.parse` has worked. However, I do not fully understand why. The model is declared this way: `var MyModel = Backbone.Collection.extend();`. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Because you declare what should be a model as an extension of a collection (apples and oranges if you want). Try `var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();` if you want to keep your  `model` attribute

Comment: A demo with your `MyModel` definition http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dcjtcx0t/ that breaks and a modified version http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dcjtcx0t/1/

Comment: Thank you for clarifying everything. I should have noticed my mistake. It was clearly obvious.